# Link to add Google Calendar event loads incorrect time

Tags: google-calendar-api, query-string

So I'm trying to create an "Add Event to Calendar" link with this format:
[https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=My+Big+Party&dates=20160320T140000Z/20160320T180000Z&details=It+will+be+crazy&location=123+Granville+St+Vancouver+BC&sf=true&output=xml](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=My%20Big%20Party&dates=20160320T140000Z/20160320T180000Z&details=It%20will%20be%20crazy&location=123%20Granville%20St%20Vancouver%20BC&sf=true&output=xml)

And it mostly works, but the time is wrong. I'm in Vancouver (same time zone as the event) and it wants to save the event from 7am to 11am (it should be 2pm to 6pm).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to convert my times to UTC but I'm getting "Call to a member function setTimeZone() on a non-object":

```
    function ls_convert_time($dt, $tz1, $df1, $tz2, $df2) {
      // create DateTime object
      $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($df1, $dt, new DateTimeZone($tz1));
      // convert timezone
      $d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz2));
      // convert dateformat
      return $d->format($df2);
    }

$new_start_time = ls_convert_time($start_time, $time_zone, 'HHmmss', 'UTC', 'HHmmss');
$new_end_time   = ls_convert_time($end_time, $time_zone, 'HHmmss', 'UTC', 'HHmmss');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519285/google-calendar-api-v3-time-zone-issues

Comment: Your template has Z at the end of the dates, that means they will be interpreted in the UTC timezone. You can for example find the UTC equivalent of the times you want and replace the current set.

Comment: I can specify the time zone by adding &ctz=America/Vancouver to the end. I'm not sure why I need to convert to UTC in that case. But if that's what I need to do, how would I do it? My time is currently formatted like this: 140000 (that would be 2pm).

Answer (score 0):

Take the Z out of the time and don´t use ctz. That´ll work for you and it[ll show the right time for the right zones